# Skrollr: How do I pause sections?

Tags: javascript, skrollr, pausing-execution

Can someone please explain the data attributes to create pausing in scenes using the Skrollr.js? I want to create a small animation but not really sure how to achieve it. Does the plugin just wait for you to finish an animation before it can scroll down to the next pause?

Comment: Can you show a demo and where you want to pause it? It'll be easier for us to tweak something existing.

Comment: The [pausing example](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/pausing.html) is really a _locking_ example, where vertical scrolling is locked while another scroll-based animation takes place. Are you talking about playing a timed animation, or is your animation also scroll-based?

Comment: I have 4 sections (or scenes) each scene will contain a scroll-based animation. I want to stop at each scene play the animation and then scroll to the next stop, play animation and so on... How can I achieve this using the skrollr plugin? By the way thanks so much for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Take a look at the example, set up a demo, and come back with the issues you have.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any pause the scrolling flow. The best way to achieve the effect you need is by doubling the height of that section and changing the position of the section content to fixed.

```
data-top-top="position: fixed"
```

Note: You should also give the appropriate z-index so that it doesn't affect the other sections.